How can I create a custom geometry node that runs a Python script?
I'd like to create a completely custom geometry node (not a node group) that for example, takes some input string, reverses it using a Python script, and then returns the output as a string in that same custom node. Even if this may be possible with some combination of existing geometry nodes, I'm interested in a Python script solution in general for other data processing.
It seems like this should easily be possible, but so far I found that you have to write the code in C++ or something and that it's not possible to do it with Python in the Scripting or Geometry Nodes section. Am I missing some obvious way to make custom nodes?

Hello and welcome to BSE. You would have to modify the Blender source code and recompile the Blender software yourself.

May I recommend to read this post comments : Creating custom node types for geometry nodes ? There are some ideas of workarounds. For explanations about why it is (still ?) not possible, I recommend this one : Is there a way to create custom Node types or Nodes Categories using Python?.
